# iOS 8's Today Widget and iCloud / NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore

Tags: ios, icloud, today-extension, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

Am I doing something wrong, or is accessing `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` from a Today Widget on iOS 8 not allowed at all?

I'm trying to access the containing app's `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`, but, for example, when I -synchronize; it returns 0, as in failed.

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: Does it also fail on a real device? I had some issues with the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore on the simulator, but on my device it works fine, even on debug builds.

Comment: I haven't yet tried it on an actual device. I will do that. Though the app itself works fine with NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore in the Simulator, that's why I didn't try it on the real device. But I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. It works on the device. Now I am so relieved, you can't believe it! Thank you so much :) Go ahead and answer so I can mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it also fail on a real device? I had some issues with the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore on the simulator, but on my device it works fine, even on debug builds.